# Java Mail - отправка сообщений в UTF-8 (поле "от кого")

Tags: java, javamail

Такая проблема.

Есть почта

```
"Моя почта" <mymail@mail.ru>
```

создаю таким образом:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(userMail));
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setText(bodyText);
```

Так вот, вместо кириллицы в поле "от" приходят крякозябры. Как исправить, хелп!?

Java Mail API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте другой конструктор класса [InternetAddress](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) и указывайте имя человека вторым параметром, а не пихайте его в основную часть. Есть ещё [конструктор с тремя параметрами](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).. там можно кодировку руками указать.

Comment: отличненько!

Comment: msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromName, "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0):

public class RunClass {

```
        public void RunClass(){}
        public void send(String smtpHost, int smtpPort, String from,String to, String subject, String content) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

            java.util.Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost); props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", ""+smtpPort);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance (props, null);
            // Construct the message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(content); 
            Transport.send(msg); 
        }
            public static void main (String args[]) throws AddressException, MessagingException{

            RunClass k = new RunClass();
            k.send("192.168.93.5", 25, "mymail@mail.ru","mymail@mail.ru", "title","Hello from app!");
            }

            }
```

Comment: Только там где айпишка - реальный smtp сервер, и порт, иначе повалят ексепшены =)

Comment: Ну и что это даёт? Это ведь всё то же самое что и было у автора и это как раз и вызвало проблемы